# What is the difference between data rate and latency?

Tags: latency, terminology

Both attempt to measure the speed of a network. If the data rate is the thing that is commonly measured in Mbps and latency is the thing that is measured in milliseconds, what are their similarities and differences?

I've tried searching google but the explanations I get are inconsistent. After searching "network latency" the first result is [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_%28engineering%29) but this definition pertains more to structural engineering than networks. The second result is [about.com](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/speedtests/a/network_latency.htm) and it states

> The term latency refers to any of several kinds of delays typically
> incurred in the processing of network data.

So does this mean latency is not a well-defined term and can mean whatever a person wants it to?

For example, when using `ping` what does the latency actually measure (and out of curiosity why doesn't ping tell the data rate, in Mbps)?

What is the perceived difference between latency and data rate, is it that latency only matters until the download (or uploaded) first part has been received?

Comment: This sounds way too much like a homework question. You may want to rephrase if it is not.

Comment: @legioxi ok well it's not a homework question, what is it about it that makes it look as such?

Comment: "what are their similarities and differences?" just came across as very homework sounding.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 12):

**Latency** is the amount of time it takes a packet of data to leave your computer and receive a response back from the end point. That is why this is measure in time. This is key for time sensitive applications like VoIP and video conferencing.

**Bandwidth/data rate** is the amount of data (bits) you can upload or download in a given time (seconds). This is key for downloads and uploads (i.e. video streaming for Hulu, Netflix, etc). It is also important in video conferencing as you're sending/receiving a lot of video (bandwidth) and the audio portion needs to be in near real time (latency).

**Ping** is sending packets using ICMP and measuring the time it takes until you receive an echo-reply from the end point. It is not sending a lot of data and would not give any accurate information regarding bandwidth.

Something like [iperf](http://iperf.sourceforge.net) may be used to measure bandwidth by sending a lot of data to the end point which also would be running perf.

You can have high latency (slow round trip time for packets) but still have a lot of bandwidth. Satellite service is one example.

Comment: So in a sense data rate measures a characteristic of a single device where as latency measures the relation between two devices?

Comment: Both measure a relationship between two devices. Data rate is measuring how much data can be sent per interval of time from one device to the other. Latency is measuring only the interval of time it takes for a packet to make a round trip.

Comment: Is there a formula that relates data rate and latency? For example `data rate = data received/time interval = data received/(latency/2)`

Comment: I am unaware of a formula.

Comment: Build your formula the other way around, it networking its called the "Bandiwdth Delay Product" - See http://www.speedguide.net/faq_in_q.php?qid=185 for examples and of course, Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Is data rate and latency usually and average? For example in Firefox your download manager says a file is being downloaded at 300Kbps. Does it literally count 300 Kb and update this value every 1 second? I am skeptical because download speeds don't fluctuate too much (over 1 second). If the latency was 2ms then could you say "the 300Kb that arrived in the past second took two ms to get here"? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @Celeritas that is a seperate question, I recommend trying to focus on one question per post: The difference between latency and data rate, do you understand what that is now? Roughly speaking, latency is the time signals take to travel down a wire and data rate is how many signals have been sent down the wire in a given time period (speed and volume respectively).

Answer (score 1):

Latency is the delay, it is measured in units of time.
Data rate is how much data can be sent per unit if time, it is not measured in data rate (per unit of time, normally a standard unit).

Data rate can affect latency in the real world, whereas latency affects bandwidth, "goodput", and I thiiink throughput.

One way to simulate data rate affecting latency is by pinging with ever-increasing packet sizes (though this has more--I believe--to do with how ICMP is handled than data rate).

One way to show data rate affecting latency is to measure latency whilst conducting a speed/bandwidth test.